# Compiling based on container type

Tags: c++

In the code below, suppose that I decided to use `deque` instead of `vector` in the definition of `mcc`. How can I bypass `cell.reserve(size)` which is not defined for `deque`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

typedef std::vector<int> mcc;
//typedef std::deque<int> mcc;

void reserve(mcc& cell, int size)
{
    cell.reserve(size);
}

int main()
{
    mcc cell;
    reserve(cell, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to define a function inside main?

Comment: If you can use C++20, this is what function templates and concepts are for.  If you can't use C++20, then you need function templates and SFINAE.

Comment: @BigTemp Yeah its wrong. I just tried to write a quick code. I didn't compile.

Comment: If you're only concerned about two possible definitions for `mcc`, just write two overloads: `void reserve(std::vector<int>& cell, int size) { cell.reserve(size); }` and `void reserve(std::deque<int>&, int) {}`.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer and some comments have pointed out, in C++20, there are concepts, a feature which makes this task fairly trivial. However, as of now, C++20 support isn't complete in any compiler.

In the current C++ version, C++17, we don't have concepts. So, we need to use templates to emulate this concept behavior:

```cpp
// The default case for can_reserve is false
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct can_reserve : std::false_type {};

// An overload of the struct allows us to verify we can call a value of type T
// If substitution doesn't fail, this overload is selected.
template<typename T>
struct can_reserve<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().reserve(1))>> : std::true_type {};

// With inline constexpr values, we can make this a type trait
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool can_reserve_v = can_reserve<T>::value;

// We can then verify we can reserve with the types
static_assert(can_reserve_v<std::vector<int>>);
static_assert(!can_reserve_v<std::deque<int>>);
```

The function then becomes:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void reserve(T& cell, int size)
{
  if constexpr(can_reserve_v<T>)
    cell.reserve(size);
}
```

Creating this kind of template is boilerplate-y and sometimes failure-prone. To solve that, we can use [the detection idiom](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/02/write-template-metaprogramming-expressively/), which reduces the boilerplate and makes the code more readable:

```cpp
// Using FluentCPP's is_detected implementation of the detection idiom
template<typename T>
using reserve_expression = decltype(std::declval<T&>().reserve(1));
 
template<typename T>
constexpr bool can_reserve_v = is_detected<reserve_expression, T>;
```

(The reserve function stays the same)

For completeness, the equivalent in C++20 would be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept can_reserve = requires(T& t){
  { t.reserve(1) };
};

template<typename T>
void reserve(T& cell, int size)
{
  if constexpr(can_reserve<T>)
    cell.reserve(size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat C++20 solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

//typedef std::vector<int> mcc;
typedef std::deque<int> mcc;

mcc cell;

template<typename T>
void reserve(T& cell, int size)
{
    if constexpr(requires{cell.reserve(size);}) {  
        cell.reserve(size);
    }
}

int main()
{    
    reserve(cell, 10);
    return 0;
}
```